# JVM: How does Scala's JavaConversions work inside Java code?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, extension-methods, implicit

I understand that Scala's [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) adds implicit conversions between various Java and Scala collections. I understand how that works in Scala, with the [`implicit`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) keyword.

However, in my case, I am running some Java code, and it has at the top:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
```

Now somehow, seemingly by magic, having that `import` at the top changes the code below when Java collections are used.

For instance, I have a method:

```
public static Collection<String> foo() { return ... }
```

and if I call that method from outside, the `Collection` instance I get back is ... altered, somehow. It has extra methods added. Through some mechanism I don't understand, that code — which does not involve Scala or JavaConversions at all — causes the class loader to bring in Scala classes.

**How does it work?**

The Java language itself does not have an `implicit` keyword or extension methods, but Scala does. Somehow, importing that Scala library is doing something low-level that (presumably) can't be expressed in Java but is still supported by the JVM.

- What happens when that `import` is encountered?
- How does Scala add methods to existing Java classes?
- What is the timing involved, here? Does something happen at `import` time, at class-load time, or something else?

Comment: I didn't work with Scala's JavaConversions, but what you describe is doable in Java through [Annotation Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) API which can modify the code at compile time.

Comment: Nothing like that should happen. My bet would be that `foo()` calls some other method which _does_ use Scala collections internally but without seeing code I can't say anything more.

Comment: Without a self contained reproduction there's really nothing useful that can be said here.

Comment: "call that method from outside" - from outside of what? "altered, somehow" - altered how? How do you know it's altered?

Answer (score 2):

Everything happens much earlier than any of that, at Scala compilation time. [The Scala compiler attempts to insert a call to an `implicit` method as a "view" in some cases that would otherwise be type errors](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/07-implicits.html#views).

The `Collection` you get back from `foo()` is just a plain old `Collection[String]`. At the point where you *use* it as a Scala collection, the Scala compiler inserts an extra method call. So if you write `foo().headOption`, this will compile to the same Java bytecode as if you had written `collectionAsScalaIterableA(foo()).headOption`, and behave like that at runtime.